# Ошибка во время обновления zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Здравствуйте!
Появилась ошибка во время обновления zabbix с 3.0 до 3.2 -

```
[Z3005] query failed: [1005] Can't create table 'zabbix.#sql-355_4' (errno: 150) [ALTER TABLE event_tag ADD CONSTRAINT c_event_tag_1 FOREIGN KEY (eventid) REFERENCES events (eventid) ON DELETE CASCADE;]
```

ОС debian wheezy, mysql, включена патриция БД.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с ней?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!

Да, сталкивался с такой проблемой.
Необходимо избавиться от партиционирования, потому что constraint'ов на поле eventid в каждой новой версии zabbix'а становится больше, и никуда от этого не деться:

1. Cлить дамп таблицы events (только данные)
   `mysqldump --no-create-info zabbix events`
2. Добавить в дамп выше первого INSERT'а

   DROP TABLE `events`;
3. После DROP TABLE должно следовать пересоздание структуры таблицы - возьмите описание events из схемы, прилагаемой к целевому дистрибутиву zabbix (файл schema.sql в подкаталоге database/, соответствующем используемой СУБД), например (на самом деле структура самой таблицы events не менялась уже очень давно и в 3.4 совпадает с 3.2):

   CREATE TABLE events (

   ```
       `eventid`                bigint unsigned                           NOT NULL,

       `source`                 integer         DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       `object`                 integer         DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       `objectid`               bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       `clock`                  integer         DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       `value`                  integer         DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       `acknowledged`           integer         DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       `ns`                     integer         DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,

       PRIMARY KEY (eventid)
   ```

   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

В результате получится SQL-скрипт, который удалит существующую таблицу events, создаст её заново без партиций, зальёт все данные INSERT-ами.

4. Остановите сервер И фронтенд zabbix, залейте SQL-скрипт от пользователя, имеющего права на создание/удаление таблиц в базе
5. Снова запустите сервер и фронтенд
6. Перенастройте хранимые процедуры или скрипт партиционирования так, чтобы для таблицы events больше не ротировались партиции
7. Добавьте в /etc/cron.d задание для регулярного удаления устаревших записей из таблицы events с запросом вида (пример для mysql):

   `DELETE FROM events WHERE clock<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-24*3600*N_DAYS);`

Где N_DAYS - количество дней, в течение которых необходимо хранить данные о событиях (обычно это 180-360 дней, но  всё индивидуально конечно :))

Вроде бы всё.